# Getting data from MySQLi using set ID not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? I'm getting the getID back fine as it's displaying when I echo on page but nothing else is getting set from database that I'm requesting.

I have tried a few things but cannot seem to crack it; I think maybe it might be bad markup from my side with the actual select query and how I put in the getID but might be wrong.

I've also added a foreach to list products, that might be wrong as well.

PHP / HTML

```
include('includes/config.php');
include('header.php');
include('functions.php');

$getID = $_GET['id'];

// Connect to the database
$mysqli = new mysqli(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASS, DATABASE_NAME);

// output any connection error
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Error : ('.$mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

// the query
$query = "SELECT i.* 
         FROM invoices as i 
         JOIN customers as c ON c.invoice = ".$getID."
         JOIN invoice_items as p ON p.invoice = ".$getID."
         ORDER BY i.invoice";

// mysqli select query
$results = $mysqli->query($query);

// mysqli select query
if($results) {

    $customer_name = $row['customer_name']; // customer name
    $customer_email = $row['customer_email']; // customer email
    $customer_address_1 = $row['customer_address_1']; // customer address
    $customer_address_2 = $row['customer_address_2']; // customer address
    $customer_town = $row['customer_town']; // customer town
    $customer_county = $row['customer_county']; // customer county
    $customer_postcode = $row['customer_postcode']; // customer postcode
    $customer_phone = $row['customer_phone']; // customer phone number

    //shipping
    $customer_name_ship = $row['customer_name_ship']; // customer name (shipping)
    $customer_address_1_ship = $row['customer_address_1_ship']; // customer address (shipping)
    $customer_address_2_ship = $row['customer_address_2_ship']; // customer address (shipping)
    $customer_town_ship = $row['customer_town_ship']; // customer town (shipping)
    $customer_county_ship = $row['customer_county_ship']; // customer county (shipping)
    $customer_postcode_ship = $row['customer_postcode_ship']; // customer postcode (shipping)

    // invoice details
    $invoice_number = $row['invoice_id']; // invoice number
    $invoice_date = $row['invoice_date']; // invoice date
    $invoice_due_date = $row['invoice_due_date']; // invoice due date
    $invoice_subtotal = $row['invoice_subtotal']; // invoice sub-total
    $invoice_shipping = $row['invoice_shipping']; // invoice shipping amount
    $invoice_discount = $row['invoice_discount']; // invoice discount
    $invoice_vat = $row['invoice_vat']; // invoice vat
    $invoice_total = $row['invoice_total']; // invoice total
    $invoice_notes = $row['invoice_notes']; // Invoice notes
    $invoice_status = $row['invoice_status']; // Invoice status

}

?>

        <h1>Edit Invoice (<?php echo $getID; ?>)</h1>
        <hr>

        <div id="response" class="alert alert-success" style="display:none;">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
            <div class="message"></div>
        </div>

        <form method="post" id="create_invoice">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="create_invoice">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <h1>
                        <img src="<?php echo COMPANY_LOGO ?>" class="img-responsive">
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 text-right">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-9">
                            <h1>INVOICE</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <select name="invoice_status" id="invoice_status" class="form-control">
                                <option value="open" <?php if($invoice_status == "open"){?>selected<?php } ?>>Open</option>
                                <option value="paid" <?php if($invoice_status == "paid"){?>selected<?php } ?>>Paid</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 no-padding-right">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group date" id="invoice_date">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="invoice_date" placeholder="Select invoice date" data-date-format="<?php echo DATE_FORMAT ?>" value="<?php echo $invoice_date; ?>" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group date" id="invoice_due_date">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="invoice_due_date" placeholder="Select due date" data-date-format="<?php echo DATE_FORMAT ?>" value="<?php echo $invoice_due_date; ?>" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group col-xs-4 float-right">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">#<?php echo INVOICE_PREFIX ?></span>
                        <input type="text" name="invoice_id" id="invoice_id" class="form-control required" placeholder="Invoice Number" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" value="<?php echo $getID; ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4>Customer Information</h4>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body form-group form-group-sm">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom copy-input required" name="customer_name" id="customer_name" placeholder="Enter name" tabindex="1" value="<?php echo $customer_name; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom copy-input required" name="customer_address_1" id="customer_address_1" placeholder="Address 1" tabindex="3" value="<?php echo $customer_address_1; ?>">    
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom copy-input required" name="customer_town" id="customer_town" placeholder="Town" tabindex="5" value="<?php echo $customer_town; ?>">        
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group no-margin-bottom">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control copy-input required" name="customer_postcode" id="customer_postcode" placeholder="Postcode" tabindex="7" value="<?php echo $customer_postcode; ?>">                  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="input-group float-right margin-bottom">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control copy-input required" name="customer_email" id="customer_email" placeholder="E-mail address" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" tabindex="2" value="<?php echo $customer_email; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom copy-input" name="customer_address_2" id="customer_address_2" placeholder="Address 2" tabindex="4" value="<?php echo $customer_address_2; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom copy-input required" name="customer_county" id="customer_county" placeholder="County" tabindex="6" value="<?php echo $customer_county; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group no-margin-bottom">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="customer_phone" id="invoice_phone" placeholder="Phone number" tabindex="8" value="<?php echo $customer_phone; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4>Shipping Information</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body form-group form-group-sm">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom required" name="customer_name_ship" id="customer_name_ship" placeholder="Enter name" tabindex="9" value="<?php echo $customer_name_ship; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom" name="customer_address_2_ship" id="customer_address_2_ship" placeholder="Address 2" tabindex="11" value="<?php echo $customer_address_2_ship; ?>">    
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group no-margin-bottom">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="customer_county_ship" id="customer_county_ship" placeholder="County" tabindex="13" value="<?php echo $customer_county_ship; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom required" name="customer_address_1_ship" id="customer_address_1_ship" placeholder="Address 1" tabindex="10" value="<?php echo $customer_address_1_ship; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom required" name="customer_town_ship" id="customer_town_ship" placeholder="Town" tabindex="12" value="<?php echo $customer_town_ship; ?>">                           
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group no-margin-bottom">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="customer_postcode_ship" id="customer_postcode_ship" placeholder="Postcode" tabindex="14" value="<?php echo $customer_postcode_ship; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- / end client details section -->
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="invoice_table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="500">
                            <h4><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-xs add-row"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></a> Item</h4>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <h4>Qty</h4>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <h4>Price</h4>
                        </th>
                        <th width="300">
                            <h4>Discount</h4>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <h4>Sub Total</h4>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        foreach($invoice_product as $key => $value) {
                            $item_product = $value;
                            // $item_description = $_POST['invoice_product_desc'][$key];
                            $item_qty = $row['invoice_product_qty'][$key];
                            $item_price = $row['invoice_product_price'][$key];
                            $item_discount = $row['invoice_product_discount'][$key];
                            $item_subtotal = $row['invoice_product_sub'][$key];
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group form-group-sm  no-margin-bottom">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete-row"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control form-group-sm item-input invoice_product" name="invoice_product[]" placeholder="Enter item title and / or description" value="<?php echo $item_product; ?>">
                                <p class="item-select">or <a href="#">select an item</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <div class="form-group form-group-sm no-margin-bottom">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control calculate" name="invoice_product_qty[]" value="1" value="<?php echo $item_qty; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm  no-margin-bottom">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><?php echo CURRENCY ?></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control calculate invoice_product_price required" name="invoice_product_price[]" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" placeholder="0.00" value="<?php echo $item_price; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <div class="form-group form-group-sm  no-margin-bottom">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control calculate" name="invoice_product_discount[]" placeholder="Enter % or value (ex: 10% or 10.50)" value="<?php echo $item_discount; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><?php echo CURRENCY ?></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control calculate-sub" name="invoice_product_sub[]" id="invoice_product_sub" value="0.00" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" value="<?php echo $item_subtotal; ?>" disabled>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div id="invoice_totals" class="padding-right row text-right">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="input-group form-group-sm textarea no-margin-bottom">
                        <textarea class-"form-control" name="invoice_notes" placeholder="Please enter any order notes here." value="<?php echo $invoice_notes; ?>"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 no-padding-right">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-6">
                            <strong>Sub Total:</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <?php echo CURRENCY ?><span class="invoice-sub-total"> <?php echo $invoice_subtotal; ?></span>
                            <input type="hidden" name="invoice_subtotal" id="invoice_subtotal" value="<?php echo $invoice_subtotal; ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-6">
                            <strong>Discount:</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <?php echo CURRENCY ?><span class="invoice-discount"> <?php echo $invoice_discount; ?></span>
                            <input type="hidden" name="invoice_discount" id="invoice_discount" value="<?php echo $invoice_discount; ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-6">
                            <strong class="shipping">Shipping:</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><?php echo CURRENCY ?></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control calculate shipping" name="invoice_shipping" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" placeholder="0.00" value="<?php echo $invoice_shipping; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php if (ENABLE_VAT == true) { ?>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-6">
                            <strong>TAX/VAT:</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <?php echo CURRENCY ?><span class="invoice-vat" data-enable-vat="<?php echo ENABLE_VAT ?>" data-vat-rate="<?php echo VAT_RATE ?>" data-vat-method="<?php echo VAT_INCLUDED ?>">0.00</span>
                            <input type="hidden" name="invoice_vat" id="invoice_vat">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-6">
                            <strong>Total:</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <?php echo CURRENCY ?><span class="invoice-total"> <?php echo $invoice_total; ?></span>
                            <input type="hidden" name="invoice_total" id="invoice_total" value="<?php echo $invoice_total; ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 margin-top btn-group">
                    <input type="submit" id="action_edit_invoice" class="btn btn-success float-right" value="Update Invoice" data-loading-text="Updating...">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <div id="insert" class="modal fade">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Select an item</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <?php popProductsList(); ?>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" id="selected">Add</button>
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Cancel</button>
              </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
          </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->

<?php
    include('footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: Done var_dump($results) and get back NULL - so maybe the SELECT query is wrong - the tables are invoices, customers and invoice_items - all contain invoice (being the ID)

Answer (score 0):

The JOINs in your query are a little strange with constants in your `ON` clauses

```
     ...
     JOIN customers as c ON c.invoice = ".$getID."
     JOIN invoice_items as p ON p.invoice = ".$getID."
     ...
```

You want this instead. Your ON clauses need to express a relationship between rows in your three tables. Putting constant values in those clauses defeats that. Instead use a `WHERE` clause to filter the correct invoice number.

```
   SELECT something, something
     FROM invoices as i 
     JOIN customers as c ON c.invoice = i.invoice
     JOIN invoice_items as p ON p.invoice = i.invoice
    WHERE i.invoice =  ".$getID."
     ORDER BY i.invoice
```

Secondly, are you sure you have a column called `invoice` in all three of these tables? Your code mentions a column called `invoice_id` later on. Is that, in fact, the name of your join column?

Thirdly, it looks like your php code expects columns from two of your three tables to appear in your result set. For example.

```
....
$customer_postcode_ship = $row['customer_postcode_ship'];
....
$invoice_number = $row['invoice_id']; 
...
```

But you did `SELECT c.*` which only returns the columns from your `customers` table.

Pro tip: Avoid `*` in `SELECT` clauses. Instead, list out the columns you want. Do something like this:

```
SELECT customer_name, customer_email, customer_address_1, customer_address_2,
      customer_town, customer_county, customer_postcode,
      customer_phone, customer_name_ship, customer_address_1_ship,
      customer_address_2_ship, customer_town_ship, customer_county_ship,
      customer_postcode_ship,
      invoice_id, invoice_date, invoice_due_date, invoice_subtotal,
      invoice_shipping, invoice_discount, invoice_vat, invoice_total,
      invoice_notes, invoice_status
 FROM ...
```

I know this seems impossibly verbose. But it's worth the effort because it allows your php code to be resilient to changes in table structure. It also makes it clear to the programmer who debugs this which columns are available in the result set.

Fourthly, keep in mind that you will get a combinatorial explosion of rows here. You're filtering for just one invoice which is fine. Presumably each invoice relates to only one customer. That too is fine. But, your customer and invoice column values will be repeated once for each matching row from your `invoice_items` table.

Fifth: check for an error return from `$mysqli->query($query);`.

```
$results = $mysqli->query($query);
if (!$results) {
        printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
} else {
   /* process the resultset */
}
```

As you work with SQL, this stuff will eventually become second nature. Don't get overly annoyed at the complexity of doing it right!

Comment: Great response Ollie, i have done a lot of changes but im having no luck! im done var_dump on results and query and i get the following:

Comment: "SELECT customer_name, customer_email, customer_address_1, customer_address_2, customer_town, customer_county, customer_postcode, customer_phone, customer_name_ship, customer_address_1_ship, customer_address_2_ship, customer_town_ship, customer_county_ship, customer_postcode_ship, invoice_id, invoice_date, invoice_due_date, invoice_subtotal, invoice_shipping, invoice_discount, invoice_vat, invoice_total, invoice_notes, invoice_status FROM invoices as i JOIN customers as c ON c.invoice = i.invoice JOIN invoice_items as p ON p.invoice = i.invoice WHERE i.invoice = 1000 ORDER BY i.invoice " NULL

Comment: the NULL i am getting from the var_dump on $results